# Failing to resolve dependencies with Unity and WebAPI

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I'm receiving this odd error when trying to run my controller action in WebAPI:

```
An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'PostController'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor.
Resolution of the dependency failed, type = "Example.Controllers.PostController", name = "(none)".
```

Exception occurred while: Calling constructor Example.Models.PostRepository().
Exception is: NullReferenceException - Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Here's the problematic code:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        var container = new UnityContainer();
        container.RegisterType<IPostRepository, PostRepository>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());

        config.DependencyResolver = new UnityResolver(container);
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "ExampleApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}"
        );
    }
}

public class PostController : ApiController
{
    IPostRepository _repository;

    public PostController(IPostRepository repository)  
    {
        _repository = repository;
    }

    public IEnumerable<Post> GetAllProducts()
    {
        return _repository.GetAll();
    }
}

public class PostRepository : IPostRepository
{
    private IDbConnection _connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString);

    public IEnumerable<Post> GetAll()
    {
        return _connection.Query<Post>("SELECT * FROM Posts").ToList();
    }
}

public class UnityResolver : IDependencyResolver
{
    protected IUnityContainer Container;

    public UnityResolver(IUnityContainer container)
    {
        if (container == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("container");
        }

        this.Container = container;
    }

    public object GetService(Type serviceType)
    {
        if (!Container.IsRegistered(serviceType))
        {
            if (serviceType.IsAbstract || serviceType.IsInterface)
            {
                return null;
            }
        }

        return Container.Resolve(serviceType);
    }

    public IEnumerable<object> GetServices(Type serviceType)
    {
        try
        {
            return Container.ResolveAll(serviceType);
        }
        catch (ResolutionFailedException)
        {
            return new List<object>();
        }
    }

    public IDependencyScope BeginScope()
    {
        var child = Container.CreateChildContainer();
        return new UnityResolver(child);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Container.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Does anyone have any idea of what might be the cause? I followed this tutorial: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/advanced/dependency-injection

Comment: I get a null on the _repository, the dependency is not fetched and my GetAll call is made to a null object.

Comment: I cannot see an issue with the Dependency Resolver you have written and it looks the same as the one in the tutorial. Make sure you have `WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration)` in the `Application_Start` method of the `Global.asax.cs` file. If this doesn't work, you can try using the Unity WebApi nuget package instead.

Comment: I have tried using the resolver inside unity webapi package, but the same error occurred. Also, i have this in my application_start: protected void Application_Start()
        {
            GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
        }

Comment: I have switched my Unity implementation to an Autofac one and i'm getting the very same error. Now i'm pretty sure it's something on my code! :(

Comment: 1- Make sure that you call WebApiConfig.Register in Application_Start method in Global.asax.cs, 2- Make sure that when you debug the api that the GetService method is get called.

Comment: Maybe it's a problem in my new SqlConnection() call, inside the PostRepository class? ps.: Both are being called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my experience when I see this message its normally some dependency is not able to be constructed or is missing a dependency. You have IPostRepository registered to PostRepository so that looks good. What about the SqlConnection created in PostRepository? Could you run some test code against just the repository to see if it constructs OK on its own?

Also just in browsing through your code is the check for interfaces blocking your resolution of the IPostRepository in the UnityResolver class?

```
    if (serviceType.IsAbstract || serviceType.IsInterface)
    {
        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The following [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/hae053g8mbq1nvv/UnityDi.zip?dl=0) has a working project which is based on the same tutorial that you mentioned.

Not much difference to your code except the database will be targeting localdb, and on the UnityResolver there is no checks for Abstract class, which doesn't make any difference I think.

Now, you can use the project as a startup point to add your logic, and know exactly when it fails and why.

hope this helps.